# angularjs solution for async $scope $apply

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I know if the call is outside angularjs or it is async then we need $apply to update the
angularjs scope.

What is the best practices to using $apply if I have many api/3rd party in my app? 
I always forgot or didn't know that api/plugin is async.

Comment: There is only one rule: always use $apply when updating Angular model outside from its scope.

Comment: Do you have some examples? Perhaps a little jsfiddle so we could rewrite it with a good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a wrapper service for each lib that needs it, and encapsulate callbacks in angular promises, but remember it's only neccessary for asynchronous functions, if you call a synchronous external lib, this should work as expected without issues.